# Работа с PChar

Tags: pascal

Дан текст. Напечатать все слова, отличные от последнего, 
предварительно преобразовав каждое из них по следующему правилу: - первую и последнюю буквы слова поменять местами;
Сделать через Pchar.

Не нашел в нете примеров наPChar. Как она будет выглядеть, знаю лишь что процедуры и функции немного другие.

Через строки:

```
  Uses CRT;

    Var
      StrMas: Array[0..199] Of String;
      Str, MStr: String;
      MasInd, StrInd, StrLen, i: Word;
      C: Char;

    Begin
      Write('Введи строку: ');
      ReadLn(Str);

      StrLen:=Length(Str);
      StrInd:=1;
      MasInd:=0;
      While (StrInd<=StrLen) Do
        Begin
          While ((Str[StrInd]=' ') And (StrInd<=StrLen)) Do
            Inc(StrInd);

          MStr:='';
          While ((Str[StrInd]<>' ') And (StrInd<=StrLen)) Do
            Begin
              MStr:=MStr+Str[StrInd];
              Inc(StrInd);
            End;

          If (MStr<>'') Then
            Begin
              C:=MStr[1];
              MStr[1]:=MStr[Length(MStr)];
              MStr[Length(MStr)]:=C;
              StrMas[MasInd]:=MStr;
            End
          Else
            Break;

          Inc(MasInd);
          Inc(StrInd);
        End;

      For i:=0 To MasInd-2 Do
        If (StrMas[i]<>StrMas[MasInd-1]) Then
          WriteLn(StrMas[i]);

      WriteLn('Нажми на любую кнопку!!!');
      Repeat Until (KeyPressed);
    End.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот то, что сумел написать:

```
Program words;

Uses
  CRT, Strings;

Var
(* этот массив у меня заполняется, но все его элементы становятся равными (не стал разбираться)
  StrMas: Array[0..199] Of Char; *)
  StrMas: Array[0..199] Of String; // с этим всё прокатывает
  Str, WordStr: Array[0..1999] Of Char;
  PStr, MStr: PChar;
  MasInd, StrInd, Len, i, j, WordInd: Word;
  C, K: Char;

Begin
  ClrScr;
  Write('Введи строку: ');

  StrInd:=0;
  Repeat
    Read(C);
    Str[StrInd]:=C;
    Inc(StrInd);
  Until (C=#13);
  Str[StrInd-1]:=#0;
  PStr:=Str;

  Len:=StrLen(PStr);
  StrInd:=0;
  MasInd:=0;
  While (StrInd<Len) Do
    Begin
      While ((PStr[StrInd]=' ') And (StrInd<Len)) Do
        Inc(StrInd);

      If (StrInd=Len) Then Break;

      WordInd:=0;
      While ((PStr[StrInd]<>' ') And (StrInd<Len)) Do
        Begin
          WordStr[WordInd]:=Char(PStr[StrInd]);
          Inc(WordInd);
          Inc(StrInd);
        End;
      MStr:=WordStr;
      MStr[WordInd]:=#0;

      If (MStr<>Nil) Then
        Begin
          C:=MStr[0];
          K:=MStr[WordInd-1];
          MStr[0]:=K;
          MStr[WordInd-1]:=C;
          StrMas[MasInd]:=String(MStr);
          Inc(MasInd);
        End
      Else
        Break;

      Inc(StrInd);
    End;

  For i:=0 To MasInd-2 Do
    If (StrMas[i]<>StrMas[MasInd-1]) Then
      WriteLn(StrMas[i]);

  WriteLn('Нажми на кнопку ANY KEY!!!');
  Repeat Until (KeyPressed);
End.
```

Comment: так все равно вводится 255 символов, потому что ты вводишь в строку. КАк записать в PChar я не знаю, этот тип лишь указатель на char